# MongoDB 3.X : Does it make sense to have only one collection per database

Tags: mongodb

Since MongoDB 3.x introduces lock per record and not on collection or database, does it make sense to write all of your data to single collection with one extra identifier field "documentType". 
It will help simulate "join" through map-reduce operation.
Couchbase does the same thing with "buckets" instead of collection.

Does anybody see any disadvatanges with this approach ?

Comment: Please elaborate your use cases. Data modeling in MongoDB *heavily* depends on them.

Comment: I may not able be give you actual data modeling info, but what i was intending to do is carry out "join" operations on different entities on mongodb server itself in single query instead of doing such a computations in your business server by having multiple calls.

Comment: No modeling + no exact use case description = `print "Yes and No. Depends on the use case."` in general, if you need to emulate a Join, there is most likely something wrong with your data model.

Comment: Really ? Coming up with the model for a given MongoDB(or  any other document oriented DB) collection and it wont have foreign key references in other collections is completely unnatural to me from real world standpoint.  Do you embed everything in single doc structure in collection ? If you do,  have you ever needed multiple collections ?

Comment: You absolutely can have references in MongoDB – albeit they are implicit. I use multiple collections every time. Let's take the bank example. I'd have a collection called `accounts` and `bookings`, which should be pretty self-explanatory. So how would I get the balance of account X? I'd run an aggregate on all bookings of the account which adds and subtracts the values of the bookings. To save time, I could have (incremental) mapReduce or aggregation jobs which write the balances of each account for the beginning of the current month to an intermediate table. Pretty much the same as in SQL.

Comment: However, contrary to what is told, data modelling in NoSQL in general and in MongoDB particularly is rather complex, since you really have to ask yourself "Which are the questions I need to get answered?". This is quite contrary to data modelling in SQL, in which you model your objects, persist them and need to find out how you get the data wou want. You might want to read [*Data Models* in the MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) for details.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg this is pretty straight forward use case where you already know `accountId` . What if i want some info like the person that account belongs to, branch or city location of that bank company ?

Comment: You still have an account collection. As for the bank info, you might want to have a linked `banks` and even a further linked `subsidiary` collection. You would link both the bank and the subsidiary to the account, for example. As always, that'd depend on the use case. The docs I mentioned explain a lot of useful stuff.

Answer (score 6):

There's one big general-case disadvantage: indexes.

With Mongo, you generally want to set up indexes so that most, if not all, queries you make, use them. So in addition to the one on `_id`, you'll set up indexes on the primary fields you search by (often compounded with those you sort by).

If you're storing everything in one single collection, that means you need to have *all* those indexes on that collection. Which means two things:

- The indexes are be bigger, since there's more documents to index. Granted, this can be somewhat mitigated by using sparse indexes.
- Inserting or modifying documents in the collection requires Mongo to update all these indexes (where it'd just update the relevant indexes in the standard use-many-collections approach). This kills your write performance.

Furthermore, if you have in your application a query that somehow doesn't use one of those many indexes, it needs to scan through the entire collection, which is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of documents in the collection -- in your case, that means the number of documents in the entire database.

Collections are cheap. Use them ;)

Comment: Thanks Max, I get your point about indexes, but according to MongoDB  guys they have made good index design (with help of WiredTiger).   How about at least merging 4-5 collections (which represent different entities of course) in single collections instead of 100 collections so that at least i can execute join operations through single query , thereby minimizing frequent calls from my business server to mongodb server to certain extent ?

Comment: Well, at this point we get to @Markus W Mahlberg's comment: data modeling depends *heavily* on your precise use case. Try it and profile it?

Comment: @MaxNoel: I fail to see where multiple collections help to reduce the combined index size. It does not make a big difference wether you have one collection with 20 index entries or two collections with 10 entries. Granted: we would save the index for `documentType`. For everything else: +1

Comment: Imagine a use case where you have 2 collections, with 10 documents each, and 1 index in each collection. You have 2 indexes indexing 10 documents each (so 20 index entries).

If you were to merge those collections into a single one differentiated by `documentType`, you end up with 3 indexes (the original 2 + the `documentType` one), indexing 20 documents each, for a total of 60 index entries.

Comment: Because we will index on different fields, in 1 collection scenario it will be 40 entries not 60 ! why would MongoDB will store the indexing info if that field does not exists ?

Comment: @user3282642 Only if the index is sparse. (which I alluded to in my initial answer)

Comment: So the extra overhead is the additional index(sparse) entries equal to number of docs. Thanks for the clarification.